# Python script doesn't have permission to change file

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, permissions

When running my Python encryption program on windows, some files return a

```
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.py", line 71, in encrypt_file
with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Is there a way I can have the Python program get permission? I've already tried running my program as an administrator, as well as some privilege elevation snippets from this website.

Here's the code:

```
with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the permissions are for your file system, but keep in mind that if you have the file open (in excel or something) to view it, the file will often be locked and python can't write to it

Comment: If there's an exclusive byte-range lock that prevents writing, you'll get a lock-violation error when you actually `write` and flush to the OS. If it's instead a sharing-violation error (file access sharing is not the same as file locking in Windows), then you won't be able to open the file for writing until the reference that's restricting write access is closed. In particular, opens that request read/execute, write/append, or delete access have to share access. Python uses read-write sharing, but not delete sharing.

Comment: Unfortunately since Python calls the C runtime `_wopen` function instead of `CreateFile` directly, there's no assurance that `GetLastError()` is valid, which is why the WinError code is not present in this exception. It may still be valid if accessed via ctypes, as may also the NT status code from `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` . Otherwise all you have is the extremely vague C `EACCES` (13) error, to which about a million error and status codes funnel into (hyperbole, but it's really a lot).

Comment: The files I experience this with are "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink\\Alphabet.xml.enc" and "C:\\users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Comms\\UnistoreDB\\store.jfm" I'm sure there's a thousand more.

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to search for open handles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to open a file with write access, so you need to use `'w'`

```
with open(out_filename, 'w') as outfile:
```

You can use specific parameter for different access,

```
'w' - Open to write 
'r' -Open to read 
'a' - Open to append at the end of the file.
```

Comment: I added the code to my original post, I need to use 'wb' to write in bytes.